# Have a Spring profile include another one (not default)

Tags: java, spring

Suppose we have 3 profiles: `default`, `foo`, `bar`. The `default` profile is the Spring "main" profile.

Let's say that if someone activates (through an argument in console) `foo` profile, then `default` profile is also enabled, but `bar` is not. This I have working.

But - and here's the issue - how can I make `bar` profile include `foo` profile which overrides the `default` one?

Comment: are you trying to activate multiple profiles at the same time? if so, you can pass the profiles to activate as a comma separated value. it should activate all the profiles provided, though properties sharing the same name will be overrided, probably by the last profile provided in the string

Comment: do you mean if foo is activated through command line , then bar should also be automatically activated even though it is not specified in the command line ?

Comment: @KenChan yes, precisely

Answer (score 1):

So you have a group of beans with a "foo" profile that you want to run in isolation if you wish, but if "bar" is activated you want to instantiate "foo" beans as well.

If this is what you meant, there are at least two ways:

**1. By using logical operators with @Profile**

The idea here is to change the profile annotation of those beans from `@Profile("foo")` to `@Profile("foo | bar")`. Now all the beans that were previously defined in the "foo" profile will be instantiated in both scenarios, if "bar" is activated or if "foo" is activated.

**2. Activating profile programmatically**

This has to be done before the ApplicationContext loads.

e.g.

```
var profiles = System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active");
    if (profiles.contains("bar"))
        System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", profiles + ",foo");
SpringApplication.run(AppConfig.class);
```

Probably not the most elegant solution but something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

no you cannot! You can copy all config in foo profile to bar profile then activate bar profile to override default profile. All configs with same name is overrided

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).